# google wallet subscription JWT 400 MERCHANT_ERROR

Tags: android-pay, jwt

When I generate and execute a non-subscription JWT in the Google developer sandbox, everything executes successfully.  However, whenever I attempt to execute a subscription JWT, I encounter a 400 / Bad Request / MERCHANT_ERROR message.

I have copied & pasted each of the resulting signed & encoded JWT into Google's JWT Decoder - which reports that each of the JWTs are valid, but only the non-subscription JWT executes successfully.

I've tried everything that I can think of.  Any help would be most appreciated.  Thanks.

### The non-subscription JWT that succeeds

```
{
    "iss":"ourSellerIdentifier",
    "aud":"Google",
    "typ":"google/payments/inapp/item/v1",
    "iat":1395879238,
    "exp":1395879298,

    "request":{
                  "name":"Professional Edition",
                  "sellerData":"10955.373715.2.1",
                  "price":"39.95",
                  "currencyCode":"USD"
              }
}
```

### The subscription JWT that generates an error

```
{
    "iss":"ourSellerIdentifier",
    "aud":"Google",
    "typ":"google/payments/inapp/item/v1",
    "iat":1395880013,
    "exp":1395880073,

    "request":{
                 "name":"Professional Edition",
                 "sellerData":"10955.373715.2.1",

                 "recurrence":{
                                 "price":"39.95",
                                 "currencyCode":"USD",
                                 "frequency":"monthly"
                              }
              }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `typ` field should be `google/payments/inapp/subscription/v1` [for subscriptions](https://developers.google.com/wallet/digital/docs/jsreference#sub) - re: "subscription" (vs "item")

Hth....